# Can get_queryset return 403 or any custom response

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, permissions

I have no idea if This is the good way to do this.
I have an endpoint, it should retrieve a specific instance of system.
Before being worried about permissions my view lookeds like this:

> class SystemDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
> """ Get a system detail """
> queryset = System.objects.all()
> serializer_class = SystemSerializer

I want to update this because I want user to be able to see only systems they own.

So I update my view like so:

```
class SystemDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
def get_queryset(self):
    user_groups = self.request.user.groups.all().values_list('name')

    if 'all_rights' not in user_groups[0]:
        if len(user_groups) == 1: # For now we say that 1 user is only in 1 group
            dealer_name: str = user_groups[0][0].capitalize() # Group name are creating progammatically, it is using the same enum than the dealer name on the system
            return System.objects.filter(dealer__name=dealer_name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('User in 2 groups, endpoint can not manage it')
    else:
        return System.objects.all()

""" Get a system detail """
serializer_class = SystemSerializer
```

So basically it works, when I try to access a system that I should not be able to see I got this message:

> {"detail":"Not found."}

but What I'd like is to set a custom message with a 403 status saying to the user he is trying to access a system he can not see.

What is the good way to achieve this ?

Thank you.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can override DRF's `APIException` class:

```
from typing import Union

from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST


class CustomAPIException(APIException):
    def __init__(
        self,
        detail: Union[str, None] = None,
        code: int = HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
    ) -> None:
        self.status_code = code
        super().__init__(detail, code)
```

Then you can raise it in your view:

```
raise CustomAPIException(
    detail={"errorMessage": "My custom error message."},
    code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
)
```